# VBA running twice per call

Tags: vba, excel

I saw this in a few other languages but didn't really see anything for VBA. Occasionally when I call a macro, it will finish a function or sub, it will redo it. It can be anything from a sub that calls 5 functions, to a simple find macro. The weird thing is, it doesn't do it all the time.

For instance, the following set of code creates a list of inventory part numbers. I clicked the play button in VBA and it ran once. I clicked play again, and it ran twice. There seems to be no rhyme or reason for whether it runs once or twice.

```
Function NumFind()

lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
Range("Q:Q").ClearContents
Range("Q4") = "Num"

For a = 5 To lastrow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(a, 16)) = False Then
        b = Range("O:O").Find(Cells(a, 16)).Address
        temp = Range(b).Offset(1, -12)
        Cells(a, 17) = Left(temp, 4)
    End If
Next

End Function
```

EDIT: Answering a few questions.

-No worksheet_change events/num finds. Before these macros, the sheets are just columns of raw data.

-I've run this from both a button on the sheet (a simple design button connected to the macro), and from the "Run Sub/Userform" on VBE and had this result.

-It's a function because I have like 10 of these that do different things, and I wanted larger subs to call so I could do different combinations of them. IE having Function A, B, C, D, E, F and having different subs to call to do A - B - C, or C - A - D, or D - E etc.

Comment: do you use this function in worksheet cells like `=NumFind()`?

Comment: Do you have a `worksheet_Change` event in the code?

Comment: @simoco: I doubt this is being called from the worksheet because of this line `Range("Q:Q").ClearContents` and the user mentioned that it works sometimes. An UDF wouldn't have worked for obvious reasons. Also the user mentioned that this is run from a button

Comment: @SiddharthRout it could work when debbuging it (not calling from sheet):)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I think `I clicked the play button in VBA and it ran once` means not button on worksheet, but button "Run Sub / Userform (F5)" on VBE

Comment: @simoco: True but this is what the user said `There seems to be no rhyme or reason for whether it runs once or twice.` A UDF will not run even once from the worksheet

Comment: This shouldn't be a `Function` to begin with. It should be a `Sub`. I would suggest making that change and see if there are still issues.

Comment: Why not add this line right after **lastrow** is calculated: `Debug.Print Now & vbTab & NumFind() & vbTab & "lastrow: " & lastrow` to confirm how many times it ran with respect to the lastrow value from the Immediate window?

Comment: Said NumFind() was an undefined function/sub.